# Python image processing library

Tags: python, image-processing, scikit-image

I want to modify image files (bmp, jpg, and png) by adding text on top of it in a specific area. For example if I were to draw an picture for an envelope and print different addresses on top in a designated area with specified fonts and colors which library would I use?

I am looking for something like this http://python-catalin.blogspot.com/2010/06/add-text-on-image-with-pil-module.html
But with a BSD license that can work with numpy and scipy with Python 3 since I just switched.

Is this a job for Scikit-image or Pillow (Not sure if it is BSD)? if not what can I use and which part of the library?

Comment: It sounds like a job for pillow. Its license is the same as PIL, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved using `freetype-py`.  See the example here: https://code.google.com/p/freetype-py/source/browse/trunk/examples/hello-world.py

This would also be a good fit for the `skimage.draw` module, and we can certainly consider adding it.

Comment: I just fininshed watching your video on Vimeo http://vimeo.com/53065496 and I am going to start using skimage. Thank you for developing such a good library. Definitely going to start using scikit-image this for more things.